# Calculate similarity of posts

Tags: php

I am using `php 7.3` and I am calculating the similarity of posts.

```
<?php

$posts = [
    'post_count' => 3,
    'posts' => [
        [
            'ID' => 1,
            'post_content' => "Wrong do point avoid by fruit learn or in death. So passage however besides invited comfort elderly be me. Walls began of child civil am heard hoped my. Satisfied pretended mr on do determine by.",
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 2,
            'post_content' => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit"
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 3,
            'post_content' => "Months on ye at by esteem desire warmth former. Sure that that way gave any fond now. His boy middleton sir nor engrossed affection excellent."
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 4,
            'post_content' => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit"
        ],
    ]
];

print_r($posts);

function getNonSimilarTexts($posts)
{
    $similarityPercentageArr = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $posts['post_count']; $i++) {
        // $posts->the_post();
        $currentPost = $posts['posts'][$i];
        if (!is_null($currentPost['ID'])) {
            for ($y = 0; $y <= $posts['post_count']; $y++) {
                $comparePost = $posts['posts'][$y];
                if (!is_null($comparePost['ID'])) {
                    similar_text(strip_tags($currentPost['post_content']), strip_tags($comparePost['post_content']), $perc);
                    // similarity is 100 if self compare
                    if ($perc != 100) {
                        array_push($similarityPercentageArr, [$currentPost['ID'], $comparePost['ID'], $perc]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $similarityPercentageArr;
}

$p = getNonSimilarTexts($posts);
print_r($p);
```

As you can see, I am getting as an output an array with the `[[ID, ID, similarity_percentage],...]`

I would like to filter this array and take out all similarities that are `>20%` and furthermore, I would like to keep only 1 similar post and remove the ohters. My wanted result are the post IDs: `1,2,3`

Any suggestions how to filter the array like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the filtering right away, changing the condition `if ($perc != 100)` to `if ($perc > 20)`, so that you only keep the similar posts that you want to get rid of. Then you could even skip storing the similarity altogether, as you already have a list of arrays of post IDs that you want to remove.

So, when you have code like this:

```
if ($perc > 20) {
    $similarityPercentageArr[$currentPost['ID']][] = $comparePost['ID'];
}
```

you can then remove all the undesired posts like this:

```
$postsToRemove = [];
$postsToKeep = [];

foreach ($similarityPercentageArr as $postId => $similarPostIds) {
    // this post has already appeared as similar somewhere, so its similar posts have already been added 
    if (in_array($postId, $postsToRemove)) {
        continue;
    }

    $postsToKeep[] = $postId;
    $postsToRemove = array_merge($postsToRemove, $similarPostIds);
}
```

Now you have the original post IDs in `$postsToKeep`, and the IDs of its similarities in `$postsToRemove`.

I would also optimize the code a little bit, so that you don't call `similar_text` at all when you know that you're comparing a post to itself. So instead `if (!is_null($comparePost['ID']))` you would have `if (!is_null($comparePost['ID']) && $comparePost['ID'] !== $currentPost['ID'])`.

Answer (score 1):

[similar_text](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)

```
similar_text — Calculate the similarity between two strings
```

[levenshtein](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

```
levenshtein — Calculate Levenshtein distance between two strings
```

[soundex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php)

```
soundex — Calculate the soundex key of a string
```

Regarding your question, after reading it back, it seems the title isn't matching much your query!

Just passing another condition isn't enough?

```
<?php

$posts = [
    'post_count' => 3,
    'posts' => [
        [
            'ID' => 1,
            'post_content' => "Wrong do point avoid by fruit learn or in death. So passage however besides invited comfort elderly be me. Walls began of child civil am heard hoped my. Satisfied pretended mr on do determine by.",
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 2,
            'post_content' => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit"
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 3,
            'post_content' => "Months on ye at by esteem desire warmth former. Sure that that way gave any fond now. His boy middleton sir nor engrossed affection excellent."
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 4,
            'post_content' => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit"
        ],
    ]
];

print_r($posts);

function getNonSimilarTexts($posts)
{
    $similarityPercentageArr = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $posts['post_count']; $i++) {
        // $posts->the_post();
        $currentPost = $posts['posts'][$i];
        if (!is_null($currentPost['ID'])) {
            for ($y = 0; $y <= $posts['post_count']; $y++) {
                $comparePost = $posts['posts'][$y];
                if (!is_null($comparePost['ID'])) {
                    similar_text(strip_tags($currentPost['post_content']), strip_tags($comparePost['post_content']), $perc);
                    // similarity is 100 if self compare and more than 20 
                    if ($perc != 100 && $perc > 20) {
                        array_push($similarityPercentageArr, [$currentPost['ID'], $comparePost['ID'], $perc]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $similarityPercentageArr;
}

$p = getNonSimilarTexts($posts);
print_r($p);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 23.145400593472
        )

)
```